# Is $B(H)$ the weak-$*$ closure of $K(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

I am getting the following result:
If $H$ is a Hilbert space, then the weak-$*$ closure of $K(H)$, the space of compact operators on $H$, is $B(H)$, the space of bounded operators on $H$.

Is this true? If it is, in what book or website can I find this result being mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of the Double Commutant theorem (See, for instance, Conway's *A Course in Operator Theory*) that for a $C^{\ast}$-subalgebra $A \subset B(H)$ that contains the identity, the weak-star closure of $A$ is $A''$. Since the identity is in the weak-star closure of $K(H)$, it follows that the weak-star closure of $K(H)$ is $K(H)'' = B(H)$.

Comment: Thank you, by the way, what is the commutant of K(H)?

Comment: It is only the scalars $\mathbb{C}I$. Just check what happens if something needs to commute with the rank one operators $x\otimes y$.

Comment: Prahlad, to use the above result, wouldn't you need to have the identity be an element in K(H)?